# use $if$ in visual studio template

Tags: c#, vsix, visual-studio-templates

Hi i am creating a vsix extension according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019) tutorial. Somewhere I need to put a code if the variable value was **True** and another one if it was **False**

In this example, Microsoft used this **$if$** command

```
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
```

I wrote a similar command but it didn't work

```
Console.WriteLine("$custommessage$"); // this line work fine and return a True value


string data = "$custommessage$"; // we have True value in data

$if$ (data.Equals("True"))
    Console.WriteLine("$custommessage$" + " This is True");
$endif$
```

Now I expect this piece of code

> Console.WriteLine("$custommessage$" + " This is True");

to be generated when creating a new project, but there is no code

Comment: What happens if you do ; `$if$ ("$custommessage$".Equals("True"))`? Maybe it's storing in an intermediate variable that doesn't work.

Comment: @PalleDue It doesn't work again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template processing doesn't execute the code in the template.

Meaning, (data.Equals("True")) is not run or executed.

Processing a template, only evaluates macros like $targetframeworkversion$ or others that you might have added to the replacements dictionary via a custom IWizard.RunStarted method.

Ed....

Comment: tnx, so how can i do this? is there any way?

Comment: $if$ ("$custommessage$" == "True")
      Console.WriteLine("$custommessage$" + "This is True");
   #endif$

Caveat, I didn't test this :-)

Comment: Where is the $if$ command documented. The template parm list on MS docs does not include this.